# Prove $\frac{a^n−b^n}{a−b}=\sum _{k=0} ^{n−1} a^kb^{n−1−k}$ by Induction

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

Let $a\ne b\in\Bbb R$. Show that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\frac{a^n−b^n}{a−b}=\sum _{k=0} ^{n−1} a^kb^{n−1−k}$$

I know using induction proof to prove it, but I can do base case but I am having trouble on proving if $n$ is true then $n+1$ is true.
Please give me some hints on this. I tried to use $n+1 - n$ but I can't let the left side equal to the right side.
My knowledge I’d only induction proof and a little bit of binomial theory.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused here. The $k$ in the problem is not the same $k$ as the one in the induction proof.

Comment: hint factor $b^{n-1}$ out of the sum, then call $r=\frac ab$. Can you sum $\sum r^k$ ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your trouble (i.e. could you put your induction process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $$f_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b},$$ you need a way to go from $f_n$ to $f_{n+1}$. Now
$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a\,\left(a^n-b^n\right)+(a-b)\,b^n,$$i.e.
$$f_{n+1}=a\,f_n+b^n.$$

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can prove this by inspection, just multiplying

\begin{align*}
a^n-b^n = (a-b)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+b^{n-3}a^2+\dots+a^{n-1})
\end{align*}

This appears in a book from Elias Stein, Complex Analysis.

Comment: Well you are just replacing the $\sum$ expression by a dotted $\cdots$ expression.

Comment: Yes, but if you multiply you get the answer. Anyway if you want to do this by induction Professor Vector gave the path.